# PHP - Consumir webservice com XML via SOAP

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

Estou tendo problemas com array em php. Eu preciso enviar um xml via soap para o webservice com alguns itens do produto, mas uma tag está me trazendo dúvidas. O manual wsdl tem um xml como este:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.edei.correios.com.br/"> <soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ser:solicitarCodigoEtiquetaInternacional>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <xml>
            <remessa>
                <idioma>PT</idioma>
                <encomendas>
                    <encomenda>
                        <cartaoDePostagem>0061962740</cartaoDePostagem>
                        <codigoControleCliente>100052202</codigoControleCliente>
                        <nomeRemetente>magento.COM</nomeRemetente>
                        <enderecoRemetente>Street Test</enderecoRemetente>
                        <numeroEnderecoRemetente>2017</numeroEnderecoRemetente>
                        <complementoEnderecoRemetente></complementoEnderecoRemetente>
                        <codigoPostalRemetente>83642</codigoPostalRemetente>
                        <cidadeRemetente>MERIDIAN</cidadeRemetente>
                        <estadoRemetente>ID</estadoRemetente>
                        <paisRemetente>US</paisRemetente>
                        <emailRemetente>sales@bodybuilding.com</emailRemetente>
                        <telefoneRemetente></telefoneRemetente>
                        <siteRemetente>www.bodybuilding.com</siteRemetente>
                        <nomeDestinatario>Junior Maia</nomeDestinatario>
                        <tipoDocumentoDestinatario>1</tipoDocumentoDestinatario>
                        <numeroDocumentoDestinatario>16549651468</numeroDocumentoDestinatario>
                        <enderecoDestinatario>Street Test</enderecoDestinatario>
                        <numeroEnderecoDestinatario>S/N</numeroEnderecoDestinatario>
                        <complementoEnderecoDestinatario>Test</complementoEnderecoDestinatario>
                        <codigoPostalDestinatario>70680506</codigoPostalDestinatario>
                        <caixaPostalDestinatario></caixaPostalDestinatario>
                        <cidadeDestinatario>Curitiba</cidadeDestinatario>
                        <ufDestinatario>PR</ufDestinatario>
                        <paisDestinatario>BR</paisDestinatario>
                        <emailDestinatario>comoquepode@gmail.com</emailDestinatario>
                        <telefoneDestinatario></telefoneDestinatario>
                        <pesoObjeto>150</pesoObjeto>
                        <comprimentoObjeto>16</comprimentoObjeto>
                        <larguraObjeto>11</larguraObjeto>
                        <alturaObjeto>2</alturaObjeto>
                        <modalidadeDistribuicaoObjeto>33375</modalidadeDistribuicaoObjeto>
                        <modalidadePagamentoImpostosObjeto>1</modalidadePagamentoImpostosObjeto>
                        <codigoMoeda>USD</codigoMoeda>
                        <valorFreteObjeto>50.00</valorFreteObjeto>
                        <valorSeguroObjeto>0.00</valorSeguroObjeto>
                        <modoDevolucaoObjeto>1</modoDevolucaoObjeto>
                        <seguroDevolucaoObjeto>N</seguroDevolucaoObjeto>
                        <itensEncomenda>
                            <itemEncomenda>
                                <codigoSHItem>100190</codigoSHItem>
                                <codigoSKUItem>TYH820040</codigoSKUItem>
                                <descricaoItem>BPI SPORTS BLOX - 110 SERVINGS - BLUEBERRY</descricaoItem>
                                <quantidadeItem>1</quantidadeItem>
                                <valorUnitario>100.00</valorUnitario>
                                <pesoUnitario></pesoUnitario>
                            </itemEncomenda>
                            <itemEncomenda>
                                <codigoSHItem>100191</codigoSHItem>
                                <codigoSKUItem>TYH820041</codigoSKUItem>
                                <descricaoItem>BPI SPORTS BLOX - 110 SERVINGS - WHITE</descricaoItem>
                                <quantidadeItem>1</quantidadeItem>
                                <valorUnitario>100.00</valorUnitario>
                                <pesoUnitario></pesoUnitario>
                            </itemEncomenda>
                            <itemEncomenda>
                                <codigoSHItem>100192</codigoSHItem>
                                <codigoSKUItem>TYH820042</codigoSKUItem>
                                <descricaoItem>BPI SPORTS BLOX - 110 SERVINGS - RED</descricaoItem>
                                <quantidadeItem>1</quantidadeItem>
                                <valorUnitario>100.00</valorUnitario>
                                <pesoUnitario></pesoUnitario>
                            </itemEncomenda>
                        </itensEncomenda>
                    </encomenda>
                </encomendas>
            </remessa>]]>
        </xml>
    </ser:solicitarCodigoEtiquetaInternacional>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Observe que a tag `<itemEncomenda>` se repete dependendo de quantos produtos o pedido possui, e é exatamente isso que não consigo alimentar no php.

Estou usando o `StdClass` para montar um array com as posições solicitadas no exemplo e montar o xml com o `SoapVar`, está funcionando para todas as tags, mas para `itemEncomenda` não! Por exemplo, eu tenho 4 itens na ordem, apenas o último está escrito na tag `<itemEncomenda>`, os outros não aparecem. Imagino que isso aconteça porque um índice `itemEncomenda` é criado na matriz e ele sobrescreve as posições antigas. Eu realmente não sei como montar uma matriz repetindo essa tag.

Aqui meu código para montar o xml com `StdClasse` montar o `xml`:

```
            $var = new StdClass;
            $var->xml = new stdClass;
            $var->xml->remessa = new stdClass;
            $var->xml->remessa->idioma = $this->idioma;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas = new stdClass;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda = new stdClass;
            //remetende
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->cartaoDePostagem  = $this->cartao_postagem;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->codigoControleCliente  = '';
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->nomeRemetente = $this->remetente_nome;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->enderecoRemetente = $this->remetente_rua;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->numeroEnderecoRemetente = $this->remetente_numero;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->complementoEnderecoRemetente = $this->remetente_complemento;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->codigoPostalRemetente  = $this->remetente_cep;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->cidadeRemetente = $this->remetente_cidade;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->estadoRemetente = $this->remetente_estado;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->paisRemetente = $this->remetente_pais;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->emailRemetente = $this->remetente_email;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->telefoneRemetente = $this->remetente_telefone;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->siteRemetente = $this->remetente_site;
            //destinatário customer
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->nomeDestinatario = $customer_nome;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->tipoDocumentoDestinatario = '1'; //1-cpf 2-cnpj 3-passport 4-not informed
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->numeroDocumentoDestinatario = $customer_taxvat;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->enderecoDestinatario = $customer_rua;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->numeroEnderecoDestinatario = $customer_rua_numero;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->complementoEnderecoDestinatario = $customer_compemento;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->codigoPostalDestinatario = $customer_cep;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->caixaPostalDestinatario = '';
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->cidadeDestinatario = $customer_cidade;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->ufDestinatario = $customer_uf;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->paisDestinatario = $customer_pais;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->emailDestinatario = $customer_email;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->telefoneDestinatario = $customer_telefone;
            //objeto
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->pesoObjeto = '';
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->comprimentoObjeto = '';
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->larguraObjeto = '';
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->alturaObjeto = '';
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->modalidadeDistribuicaoObjeto = $this->modalidade_distribuicao_objeto;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->modalidadePagamentoImpostosObjeto = $this->modalidade_pagamento_imposto;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->codigoMoeda = $this->moeda;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->valorFreteObjeto = '';
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->valorSeguroObjeto = '';
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->modoDevolucaoObjeto = $this->modo_devolocao;
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->seguroDevolucaoObjeto = $this->seguro_devolucao ;
            //itens
            $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->itensEncomenda = new stdClass;

            foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item){
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                $item_name = $item->getName();
                $item_sku = $item->getSku();
                $item_id = $item->getProductId();
                $item_qty = $item->getQty();
                $item_price = $item->getPrice();
                $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item_id);
                $item_peso = $_product->getWeight();

                $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->itensEncomenda->itemEncomenda = new stdClass;
                $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->itensEncomenda->itemEncomenda->codigoSHItem = '';
                $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->itensEncomenda->itemEncomenda->codigoSKUItem = $item_sku;
                $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->itensEncomenda->itemEncomenda->descricaoItem = $item_name;
                $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->itensEncomenda->itemEncomenda->quantidadeItem = $item_qty;
                $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->itensEncomenda->itemEncomenda->valorUnitario = $item_price;
                $var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->itensEncomenda->itemEncomenda->pesoUnitario = $item_peso;

            }

            print_r($var);
```

A saída no console é um array exatamente conforme necessário, mas com apenas 1 item, e `$invoice->getAllItems()`há 5!

Saída do array acima:

```
2017-12-14T18:17:04+00:00 DEBUG (7): stdClass Object
(
    [xml] => stdClass Object
        (
            [remessa] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idioma] => PT
                    [encomendas] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [encomenda] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [cartaoDePostagem] => 0057018901
                                    [codigoControleCliente] => 
                                    [nomeRemetente] => 
                                    [enderecoRemetente] => 
                                    [numeroEnderecoRemetente] => 
                                    [complementoEnderecoRemetente] => 
                                    [codigoPostalRemetente] => 
                                    [cidadeRemetente] => 
                                    [estadoRemetente] => 
                                    [paisRemetente] => 
                                    [emailRemetente] => 
                                    [telefoneRemetente] => 
                                    [siteRemetente] => 
                                    [nomeDestinatario] => joao teste
                                    [tipoDocumentoDestinatario] => 1
                                    [numeroDocumentoDestinatario] => 69077886168
                                    [enderecoDestinatario] => addrees test 
                                    [numeroEnderecoDestinatario] => 16
                                    [complementoEnderecoDestinatario] => Sandu Norte
                                    [codigoPostalDestinatario] => 99988009
                                    [caixaPostalDestinatario] => 
                                    [cidadeDestinatario] => Brasília
                                    [ufDestinatario] => DF
                                    [paisDestinatario] => BR
                                    [emailDestinatario] => joaoteste1234@gmail.com
                                    [telefoneDestinatario] => (61) 9000-0000
                                    [pesoObjeto] => 
                                    [comprimentoObjeto] => 
                                    [larguraObjeto] => 
                                    [alturaObjeto] => 
                                    [modalidadeDistribuicaoObjeto] => 33367
                                    [modalidadePagamentoImpostosObjeto] => 1
                                    [codigoMoeda] => BRL
                                    [valorFreteObjeto] => 
                                    [valorSeguroObjeto] => 
                                    [modoDevolucaoObjeto] => 1
                                    [seguroDevolucaoObjeto] => 1
                                    [itensEncomenda] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [itemEncomenda] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [codigoSHItem] => 
                                                    [codigoSKUItem] => LI-60669896245-preto
                                                    [descricaoItem] => Smartwatch DZ09 Câmera 2.0 MP Bluetooth Conectividade Redes Sociais Fashion - Preto
                                                    [quantidadeItem] => 2.0000
                                                    [valorUnitario] => 49.9000
                                                    [pesoUnitario] => 0.4000
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Deveria ser assim (com 5 tags `[itemEncomenda]`) para montar o xml corretamente:

```
2017-12-14T18:17:04+00:00 DEBUG (7): stdClass Object
(
    [xml] => stdClass Object
        (
            [remessa] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [idioma] => PT
                    [encomendas] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [encomenda] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [cartaoDePostagem] => 0057018901
                                    [codigoControleCliente] => 
                                    [nomeRemetente] => 
                                    [enderecoRemetente] => 
                                    [numeroEnderecoRemetente] => 
                                    [complementoEnderecoRemetente] => 
                                    [codigoPostalRemetente] => 
                                    [cidadeRemetente] => 
                                    [estadoRemetente] => 
                                    [paisRemetente] => 
                                    [emailRemetente] => 
                                    [telefoneRemetente] => 
                                    [siteRemetente] => 
                                    [nomeDestinatario] => joao teste
                                    [tipoDocumentoDestinatario] => 1
                                    [numeroDocumentoDestinatario] => 00000000
                                    [enderecoDestinatario] => address test
                                    [numeroEnderecoDestinatario] => 16
                                    [complementoEnderecoDestinatario] => Sandu Norte
                                    [codigoPostalDestinatario] => 00000000
                                    [caixaPostalDestinatario] => 
                                    [cidadeDestinatario] => Brasília
                                    [ufDestinatario] => DF
                                    [paisDestinatario] => BR
                                    [emailDestinatario] => joaoteste1234@gmail.com
                                    [telefoneDestinatario] => (61) 9000-0000
                                    [pesoObjeto] => 
                                    [comprimentoObjeto] => 
                                    [larguraObjeto] => 
                                    [alturaObjeto] => 
                                    [modalidadeDistribuicaoObjeto] => 33367
                                    [modalidadePagamentoImpostosObjeto] => 1
                                    [codigoMoeda] => BRL
                                    [valorFreteObjeto] => 
                                    [valorSeguroObjeto] => 
                                    [modoDevolucaoObjeto] => 1
                                    [seguroDevolucaoObjeto] => 1
                                    [itensEncomenda] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [itemEncomenda] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [codigoSHItem] => 
                                                    [codigoSKUItem] => LI-60669896245-preto
                                                    [descricaoItem] => Smartwatch DZ09 Câmera 2.0 MP Bluetooth Conectividade Redes Sociais Fashion - Preto
                                                    [quantidadeItem] => 2.0000
                                                    [valorUnitario] => 49.9000
                                                    [pesoUnitario] => 0.4000
                                                )
                                            [itemEncomenda] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [codigoSHItem] => 
                                                    [codigoSKUItem] => LI-60669896245-branco
                                                    [descricaoItem] => Câmera 2.0 MP Bluetooth Conectividade Redes Sociais Fashion - Branco
                                                    [quantidadeItem] => 2.0000
                                                    [valorUnitario] => 49.9000
                                                    [pesoUnitario] => 0.4000
                                                )
                                            [itemEncomenda] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [codigoSHItem] => 
                                                    [codigoSKUItem] => LI-60669896245-vermelho
                                                    [descricaoItem] => Smartwatch DZ09 Câmera 2.0 MP Bluetooth Conectividade Redes Sociais Fashion - Vermelho
                                                    [quantidadeItem] => 3.0000
                                                    [valorUnitario] => 49.9000
                                                    [pesoUnitario] => 0.4000
                                                )
                                            [itemEncomenda] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [codigoSHItem] => 
                                                    [codigoSKUItem] => LI-60669896245-verde
                                                    [descricaoItem] => Câmera 2.0 MP Bluetooth Conectividade Redes Sociais Fashion - Verde
                                                    [quantidadeItem] => 1.0000
                                                    [valorUnitario] => 49.9000
                                                    [pesoUnitario] => 0.4000
                                                )
                                            [itemEncomenda] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [codigoSHItem] => 
                                                    [codigoSKUItem] => LI-60669896245-cinca
                                                    [descricaoItem] => Câmera 2.0 MP Bluetooth Conectividade Redes Sociais Fashion - Cinza
                                                    [quantidadeItem] => 4.0000
                                                    [valorUnitario] => 49.9000
                                                    [pesoUnitario] => 0.4000
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Talvez esse xml não deva ser montado com array, pois a tag `itemEncomenda` precisa aparecer várias vezes (de acordo com a quantidade produtos do foreach) no mesmo XML, isso significa (a meu ver) que teria que repetir o key do array com o mesmo nome, o que não é permitido no PHP.

Eu tentei também criar um array conforme demonstrado abaixo, mas tropeço no mesmo problema, array com key com o mesmo nome:

```
$soapArgs = array(
                'xml' => array(
                    'remessa' => array(
                        'idioma' => 'PT',
                        'encomendas' => array(
                            'encomenda' => array(
                                //remetende
                                'cartaoDePostagem' => $this->cartao_postagem,
                                'codigoControleCliente' => '',
                                'nomeRemetente' => $this->remetente_nome,
                                'enderecoRemetente' => $this->remetente_rua,
                                'numeroEnderecoRemetente' => $this->remetente_numero,
                                'complementoEnderecoRemetente' => $this->remetente_complemento,
                                'codigoPostalRemetente' => $this->remetente_cep,
                                'cidadeRemetente' => $this->remetente_cidade,
                                'estadoRemetente' => $this->remetente_estado,
                                'paisRemetente' => $this->remetente_pais,
                                'emailRemetente' => $this->remetente_email,
                                'telefoneRemetente' => $this->remetente_telefone,
                                'siteRemetente' => $this->remetente_site,
                                //destinatário customer
                                'nomeDestinatario' => $customer_nome,
                                'tipoDocumentoDestinatario' => 1, //1-cpf 2-cnpj 3-passport 4-not informed
                                'numeroDocumentoDestinatario' => $customer_taxvat,
                                'enderecoDestinatario' => $customer_rua,
                                'numeroEnderecoDestinatario' => $customer_rua_numero,
                                'complementoEnderecoDestinatario' => $customer_compemento,
                                'codigoPostalDestinatario' => $customer_cep,
                                'caixaPostalDestinatario' => '',
                                'cidadeDestinatario' => $customer_cidade,
                                'ufDestinatario' => $customer_uf,
                                'paisDestinatario' => $customer_pais,
                                'emailDestinatario' => $customer_email,
                                'telefoneDestinatario' => $customer_telefone,
                                //objeto
                                'pesoObjeto' => '',
                                'comprimentoObjeto' => '',
                                'larguraObjeto' => '',
                                'alturaObjeto' => '',
                                'modalidadeDistribuicaoObjeto' => '',
                                'modalidadePagamentoImpostosObjeto' => '',
                                'codigoMoeda' => '',
                                'valorFreteObjeto' => '',
                                'valorSeguroObjeto' => '',
                                'modoDevolucaoObjeto' => '',
                                'seguroDevolucaoObjeto' => '',
                                //itens
                                'itensEncomenda' => array(
                                    'itemEncomenda' => array(
                                        'codigoSHItem' => '',
                                        'codigoSKUItem' => '',
                                        'descricaoItem' => '',
                                        'quantidadeItem' => '',
                                        'valorUnitario' => '',
                                        'pesoUnitario' => ''
                                    ), //itemEncomenda
                                    'itemEncomenda' => array(
                                        'codigoSHItem' => '',
                                        'codigoSKUItem' => '',
                                        'descricaoItem' => '',
                                        'quantidadeItem' => '',
                                        'valorUnitario' => '',
                                        'pesoUnitario' => ''
                                    ), //itemEncomenda
                                    'itemEncomenda' => array(
                                        'codigoSHItem' => '',
                                        'codigoSKUItem' => '',
                                        'descricaoItem' => '',
                                        'quantidadeItem' => '',
                                        'valorUnitario' => '',
                                        'pesoUnitario' => ''
                                    ), //itemEncomenda
                                ), //itensEncomenda
                            ), //encomenda
                        ), //encomendas
                    ), //remessa
                ) //xml
            );
```

Percebe-se que dentro do array `'itensEncomenda' => array(várias key com itemEncomenda)`, e é aqui que eu não consigo achar uma solução.

Talvez deveria montar o XML com `XWMWrite()` ou `SimpleXML()` mas aí eu me deparo com o problema de não conseguir colocar um XML feito na "mão" dentro de um SoapVar() para enviar no padrão correto que o webservice `wsdl` espera.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz nisso?

Comment: Oi Junior Maia! A tua pergunta foi marcada automáticamente como excessivamente longa. Se for possivel encurtar e deixar apenas as partes importantes aumentas a possibilidade de outros disporem de tempo para ler e ajudar.

Comment: Sugiro que remova informações sigilosas (como endereço, nome, telefone, nº documento) e adicione informações fictícias, evitando a exposição dessas informações na rede.

Answer (score 0):

Junior, não sei se stdClass é a melhor abordagem para gerar esse XML. Acredito que o ideal seria usar um objeto SimpleXMLElement para gerar tudo. Outra abordagem, seria converter tudo em Array.
Bom, no caso do seu código, o problema é que "**itensEncomenda**" precisa ser um Array, do contrário você vai sempre sobrescrever o ultimo indice cadastrado.

Na linha:

```
$var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->itensEncomenda = new stdClass;
```

você deve substituir por:

```
$var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->itensEncomenda = Array();
```

E dentro do Foreach, o melhor é simplificar o código fazendo:

```
...
$itemEncomenda = new stdClass;
$itemEncomenda->codigoSHItem = '';
$itemEncomenda->codigoSKUItem = $item_sku;
$itemEncomenda->descricaoItem = $item_name;
$itemEncomenda->quantidadeItem = $item_qty;
$itemEncomenda->valorUnitario = $item_price;
$itemEncomenda->pesoUnitario = $item_peso;

$var->xml->remessa->encomendas->encomenda->itensEncomenda[] = $itemEncomenda;
```

Dessa forma você cria um Array e não sobrescreve nenhum dos itens. 
Mas como lhe informe acima e volto a frisar, o ideal seria você criar a estrutura toda como Array e ao final converte-la para XML por ser mais flexível dessa forma.

Qualquer dúvida informe, abs.

Comment: mas se itensEncomenda for array(), ele vai criar index numérico nas posições, aí onde deveria ser 'itemEncomenda' vai ficar '0' '1'.. E ai o wsdl não vai reconhecer a tag. Será que não deveria ser um ArrayObject com SoapVar() ?